# Why does my constructor's "this" variable stay private?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple JS tree library, so I can dynamically create markup for hierarchical data.

Question: Why does "var that = this;" stay private, when I use the Tree constructor to return a new object instance? I'm glad "that" is private, but I don't know WHY it's private. Thoughts?

```
function Tree(data, containerId) {
    var that = this; // Private variable. Not returned by constructor, because... ???

    this.data = data;
    this.container = document.getElementById(containerId);
    this.selectedNodeId = null;
    this.container.addEventListener('click', function (e) { 
        that.selectedNodeId = e.target.getAttribute('id');
        console.log(that.selectedNodeId);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on closures. --- Why use `that` instead of `this`?

Comment: Short answer closures. Long answer closures.

Comment: Have you used the constructor with the `new` operator like: `new Tree()`

Comment: It's all about closures, but If you want to learn and understand "this" in Javascript, you can read this article by hackernoon, https://hackernoon.com/javascript-the-keyword-this-for-beginners-fb5238d99f85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at closures, anything defined in a Javascript function remains in there. There are loads of great resources such as https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Closures is covered in depth :)

Comment: Are you sure the terminology is correct? A closure closes over free variables - but `this` isn't a free variable when constructed with `new`. And `that` is just a locally scoped `var`.

Comment: You're right; "that" is a private variable, NOT a public property (like I thought I was creating for some reason). If I did something like "this.that = this;" (if that even compiles), then I'd be creating a public property but that's not what I'm doing. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :) I cant recommend the book series enough too. (I'm not Kyle Simpson)

Comment: What's ridiculous is I know what a closure is and I even referred to the variable as "private variable" in my code, yet I still thought I was somehow assigning a public property to Tree. I guess I needed to read what I was doing from someone else for it to stick. :)

Comment: Haha we all do it mate

Answer (score 1):

`new Tree(...)` **will** return the value of `that` (and `this`). Simply invoking `Tree(...)` will not.

The `new` operator returns the resulting object (ie. `this`) if nothing is explicitly returned. Simply calling the function will (in this case) return `undefined`.

Comment: Maybe we're not on the same page, but doing something like "var t = new Tree(...)" won't make "t.that" return anything but undefined. For example:

Comment: function Tree(data, containerId) {
 // Private "closure" variable (variable being the operative word, not "property")
 var that = this; 
 
 // Public properties
 this.data = data;
 this.container = document.getElementById(containerId);
 this.selectedNodeId = null;
}

// t = new instance of Tree
var t = new Tree('some data here','111');

console.log('Iterate thru t\'s properties:'); 
for (p in t) {
 console.log(p);
}

console.log('t.that is a public property of t? ' + t.hasOwnProperty('that')); // returns false.

Comment: Thanks for being willing to help, though! I appreciate it.